# how to make a video call in windows phone?

Tags: video, calls

how to do the video call in windows phone without Skype. 3g network also provide the video call facility to customer. in windows phone i am not able to do video calling without Skype. its this possible or not

any one please share the information about this.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make a video call with a Windows Phone is to use [Skype](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/get-skype/9wzdncrfj364) o some similar software.

There is no native support to 3G video calls on WP, like on iOS or Android.

The costly video call service provided directly by some ISP on their 3G networks (an innovation circa ten years ago) is now provided by several different Apps: the default one on WP is Skype, on iOS there is FaceTime and on Android you have Hangouts, but there also are many 3rd-party Apps available on all the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IMO](https://www.imo.im/), it has video chat and works even in Edge for text messaging and audio. On my phone IMO heats up the battery, becomes very hot in a few minutes.

Comment: Too bad windows phone doesn't have too much options on video chat , I've try Telegram but doesn't make video and audio, only text